# How to reconstruct the 3D coordinate system using feature points from an image?

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d, coordinate-transformation

Given a picture of a rubiks cube, is it possible to construct the world space by using feature points from the faces and edges in the image?

By using some Topological Data Analysis methods I can take an image of a rubiks cube and identify the squares on each face. I can also determine the vertices and edges that are visible (see examples below). Using this data, it is possible to separate the faces and find associated angles. There seems to be plenty of information to construct a 3D model of the cube, but I cannot figure out how.

#### Examples of Feature Points

[image: Cube with faces identified]

[image: Cube with faces and edges identified]

I was able to reconstruct a 2D model of the cube with each face colored correctly. The issue is still that there is no depth to the model.

[image: 2D model of the cube]

I tried calculating the depth as a function of the distance from the center vertex (see below). This didn't work because it created a cone instead of flat faces. **I think I will need to use some sort of transformation matrix to get this to work properly.**

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

# Function to get the depth values
# based on distance from the center vertex
def zVal(xPts, yPts, center, theta):
    zLst = np.zeros(xPts.shape).flatten()
    tan = np.tan(np.deg2rad(theta))
    x = xPts.flatten()
    y = yPts.flatten()
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        dist = np.linalg.norm(np.array([x[i],y[i]]) - np.array(center))
        zLst[i] = (dist*tan)
    return zLst.reshape(xPts.shape)

# X and Y data comes from lstPairs0 which is a list of each line that 
# connects the feature points on a face
xs = np.array(sum(lstPairs0, [])).T[0].reshape((8,9))
ys = np.array(sum(lstPairs0, [])).T[1].reshape((8,9))
# calculating depth values
zs = (zVal(xs, ys, [175,140], 45))

ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs)
plt.show()
```

Here is some sample data for the lines on one of the faces. Each row in the array is three feature points that make a line.

```py
lstPairs = [[[216.0, 207.0], [239.0, 181.0], [259.0, 158.0]],
 [[216.0, 207.0], [185.0, 213.0], [144.0, 221.0]],
 [[221.0, 66.0], [242.0, 94.0], [262.0, 121.0]],
 [[221.0, 66.0], [187.0, 58.0], [146.0, 49.0]],
 [[92.0, 136.0], [104.0, 167.0], [118.0, 199.0]],
 [[92.0, 136.0], [104.0, 104.0], [119.0, 66.0]],
 [[259.0, 158.0], [207.0, 185.0], [144.0, 221.0]],
 [[262.0, 121.0], [210.0, 90.0], [146.0, 49.0]]]
```

The transformation matrix is probably the key, but please let me know what y'all think!

Comment: Have you thought of constructing the 3d space first then assigning the colors to the faces since you already seem to be able to do that?